# Does Rails have anything like Django Rest Framework?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I come from the Django world and have found Django Rest Framework to be a useful way to make REST API's. It helps eliminate the boilerplate and comes with nice prebuilt modules for auth, serialization, etc.

I'm wondering if Rails has anything similar?

Comment: You can use [grape gem](https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape) in rails. Plus you can follow [this blog](http://joshsymonds.com/blog/2013/02/22/existing-rails-api-solutions-suck/) to check few other gems available out there.

Answer (score 4):

Rails 5 has the new feature **API mode**, could fit your needs. Check more from [here](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2016/6/30/Rails-5-0-final/#api-mode).

Answer (score 1):

Disclosure: I am promoting a gem that I authored.

I am a software engineer who loves Python/Django but who has worked with Ruby on Rails for about 5 years; recently, I wrote a gem called [Rails REST Framework](https://rails-rest-framework.com). The core goal is to provide similar base functionality as DRF, namely:

- `ModelControllerMixin` (analogous to `ModelViewSet`), which allow controllers to include the common CRUD actions and `api_response` renderer.
- Routers, which allow routing to actions which are defined on Controllers.
- Serializers (mainly the `NativeModelSerializer`, which allow you to define fields, ignore/exclude fields, methods, and associations/relations).
- Browsable APIs (included with the `ModelControllerMixin`) allow your APIs to be browsable (and the theme I kinda shamelessly stole from DRF).